# Issue with sqlite3_column_double

Tags: objective-c, double

I have a feeling I'm asking a stupid question here. I'm having trouble retrieving float values from a database.

The field in the database (whether I set it to float or double, I've tried both)
Has the value

-3.218364

When reading the value using sqlite3_column_double it returns the value

194586

I've tried all sorts of combinations, storing it using float, double, NSNumber, CLLocationDegrees with no luck at all.

How stupid am I being here, I've used decimals in previous app with no problems. But I can't figure out what I've done wrong here.

All help appreciated!

Comment: try NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(stmt, col)];    //NSLog(@"float = %f", [number floatValue]);

Comment: It returns 194586.000000 instead

Comment: How did you save it `sqlite3_bind_double`? And remember that indexes for binding are 1 based while retrieving is 0 based.

Comment: It turns out the client provided me with the wrong database! Thanks for your time. Much appreciated

Comment: Ahh so the problem was inserting the wrong value :) I knew something was up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite will store and retrieve the correct value as long as you bind the correct value and use the correct indexes.

e.g.

```
//prepare insert statement ...
sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 1, -3.218364); //Binding is 1 based

//.. retrieve
double dv = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0); //Retrieving is 0 based
```

You should not be getting another value unless

1. You are inserting the wrong value
2. You are retrieving from the wrong index